# Creating all strongly connected graphs with given in-degree with equal probability

Tags: algorithm, graph, probability, graph-theory

I am looking for a way to sample **uniformly** from the space of all **strongly connected directed** graphs (without self-loops) of `n` nodes and in-degree `k=(k_1,...,k_n), 1 <= k_i <= n-1`.

**Input**

- `n`, the number of nodes
- `k = (k_1,...,k_n)`, where `k_i =` number of directed edges that enter node `i` (in-degree)

**Output**

- a strongly connected directed graph of `n` nodes (without self-loops) with the given in-degrees `k_1,...,k_n` where each possible such graph is returned with the **same** probability.

I am particularly interested in cases where `n` is large and `k_i` is small so that simply creating a graph and checking for strong connectedness is unfeasible because the probability is essentially **zero**.

I looked through all sorts of papers and methods but couldn't find anything that deals with this problem.

Comment: I think this question might be better for http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Can there be parallel arcs?

Comment: No, no parallel arcs. Only one edge from node i to j is allowed but for sure, there can be two edges (i,j) and (j,i).

Comment: Can't you create a random Eulerian circuit first, so you satisfy the connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

Keep creating a random path until there is a loop:

node1->node2->node3...->nodek->noder where r<=k

Now, replace the cycle noder->noder+1->nodek with a blob and let us call it blobr. Now keep connecting it to the remaining nodes (such that nodes are not in this blob). Every time you hit a cycle, just create a bigger blob.

This will ultimately create a random minimally strong directed graph. Afterwards, add random edges to fulfill incoming criteria.

This will definitely create all the combinations of your requirements. I think all the combinations are equally likely, but I have to think more.

Algorithm: This is a rough scheme. I am actually not reconding the graph structure here and not addressing the edge conditions, but that should be pretty straighforward.

```
function randomStrongGraph(list<set<node>> chain, set<node> allnodes)
    Node newnode = random(allnodes - head(chain))
    alreadyEncountered = false
    for (i=0,i<chain.length-1;i++)
        if (newnode in chain(i))
            consolidate(chain, i)
            alreadyEncountered = true
            break
    if !alreadyEncountered
        chain.append(new set().add(newnode))    
    randomStrongGraph(chain, allnodes)
```

Comment: What happens if you get too many edges during the first step?

Comment: @ThomasAhle You cannot. The number of edges in the first step is O(n).